# Horizontal scroll on text input

Tags: overflow, react-native, textinput

I got two input text. First one is for an email, the problem comes when I write more text than the width of this input, the rest of the text doesn't see. The normal behavior would be scroll horizontally to see the rest of the text, right?

I don't know if I'm missing something, but it doesn't work.

Here is the example code: [rnplay.org](https://rnplay.org/apps/TcIR0A)

**Edit:** This is the effect I wanna get, this is from UI Explorer Example from official React Native repo:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was be able to solve it.

I don't know why, but the problem comes if I have set both **paddingTop** and **paddingBottom** to the input text.

If I remove one of them, then the input text works perfectly, here is an example: [Input text working well](https://rnplay.org/apps/aDQWoQ)

I hope this can help someone too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I threw a hacky thing together [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/q7M2Pg), basically wrapping the TextInput in a horizontal ScrollView:

https://rnplay.org/apps/q7M2Pg

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
  <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{ marginBottom:-7 }}>                        
     <TextInput
        style={ [styles.loginFormInput, {width:width}] } />
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Theoretically to make this better, you could call an `onChangeText` method to set the width to make it nicer (though a native way would be ideal of course).

Don't see any configuration for that in the source at all however, hopefully someone can come along with a better answer!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nader.

Is it not possible what I want?

I want only one line which move forward when the text reaches the end by the right side.

Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Hey, sorry didn't realize you said horizontal! I've updated my answer, best of luck to you.

Comment: In the UI Explorer example from Real Native official repository, it works well, but I don't see nothing special in the code, so, I don't know how to do it!

I've edited my question with a gif that shows the effect.