# Horizontal Scroll on TextInput React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, uitextinput

I have a TextInput that is not scrolling when the underlying text overflows the input on iOS. On Android the component is behaving normally as I expect, that is, whenever the text overflows the input it scrolls until the caret is visible and I can move the caret around. (I don't know if I fully explained myself).

Searching on Google I found the same question:

[Horizontal scroll on text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003358/horizontal-scroll-on-text-input/35021522)

But the selected answer is not working for me. Has anyone faced the same difficulties? How can I resolve them? Why is it working on Android and not on iOS?

Comment: can you share your code with us?

Comment: Not really, I haven't found a way to reproduce the bug outside of the app :/

Comment: Just share your particular .js which content this behavior, so others can help you more. We can't help you if you give no code